SQLModel select with except, field from list
Where we are
Having a list of ids, I want to query a table records (that has the fields id and insertion_date) to show me all ids from the list, with insertion_date after a certain date, that are NOT in the table.
I can do this in postgreSQL  with :

SELECT * 
from ( values 
        (1), 
        (2), 
        (3), 
        (4)
    ) AS t(id) -- This is my list of ids in a way that sql makes the except work
except
select r.id
from records r 
where r.insertion_date > '2024-08-01'


However, I was not able to find out how to do the first select above the except command  in sqlmodel or sqlalchemy. The issue is that these ids are not coming from the database, they are a list coming from another source. So I cannot just do another query first. SQLModel and SQLalchemy only accept queries in the .except_() method in except.
What I want to do
How can the same result from the SQL query be achieved using either of those python libraries?
